# Flex: handle mouse and touch event differently

Tags: apache-flex, mouseevent, touch-event

I have a Flex app that user mouseOver functionality to display a tooltip that I now need to make touch enabled. To do this I would like to detect a difference between a `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN` and a `TouchEvent.TAP`. On the TouchEvent I would then start a Timer and when the Timer finishes the TouchEvent will be handled as a `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN`.

The problem is that it does not appear to be possible to have both MouseEvent and TouchEvent handlers available at the same time. If the MouseEvent handler is added then the TouchEvent will never fire. It also does not seem possible to detect if the MouseEvent was actually triggered by the TouchEvent.

Does anyone know how to have both MouseEvent and TouchEvent functionality in the same Flex app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the most part, you can just rely on `MouseEvent` in AIR for Mobile. I have never had an issue with them. Is there a specific reason you want to use `TouchEvent` over `MouseEvent` other than it seems like the correct thing to do?

Either way, to accept touch input in this manner, you need to set the following global flag:

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Multitouch.html#inputMode

The default is `GESTURE`, which does not dispatch the `TAP` event.

> Specifies that events are dispatched only for basic touch events, such as a single finger tap. When you use this setting, events listed in the TouchEvent class are dispatched; events listed in the TransformGestureEvent, PressAndTapGestureEvent, and GestureEvent classes are not dispatched.

[Source](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/MultitouchInputMode.html#TOUCH_POINT)